# Multi-tenant schema with Liquibase

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, database-migration, liquibase

I am currently fighting with the following problem: I have a Java EE application and want to use Liquibase as a DB migration tool. The problem is that I have multi-tenant model and each tenant has its own schema. Currently I am using a producer to start an update but not sure how to configure it to work with different schema.

I've found that there is some solution for Spring (see MultiTenantSpringLiquibase for more details). However, there is no solution for Java EE. Maybe the only solution is to write custom Liquibase servlet listener.

Thanks for any help and best regards, Erno

Answer (score 0):

If you have a different schema name for each tenant, than you may want to use Maven liquibase plugin.

You may want to declare different execution for each schema as below:

```
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!--NOTE: clearCheckSums=true attribute will make the changesets run only once.
                        The runOnChange attribute added to changesets will not work as originally intended.-->
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${database.liquibase.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>admin-schema-database-update</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <changeLogFile>admin-schema.db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                                <driver>${database.driver}</driver>
                                <contexts>${database.liquibasecontext}</contexts>
                                <url>${database.server.url}</url>
                                <username>${database.adminschema.username}</username>
                                <password>${database.adminschema.password}</password>
                                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                                <outputDefaultSchema>true</outputDefaultSchema>
                                <verbose>true</verbose>
                                <logging>${database.liquibase.logging}</logging>
                                <propertyFileWillOverride>false</propertyFileWillOverride>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>update</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>user-schema-database-update</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <changeLogFile>user-schema.db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                                <driver>${database.driver}</driver>
                                <contexts>${database.liquibasecontext}</contexts>
                                <url>${database.server.url}</url>
                                <username>${database.username}</username>
                                <password>${database.password}</password>
                                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                                <outputDefaultSchema>true</outputDefaultSchema>
                                <verbose>true</verbose>
                                <logging>${database.liquibase.logging}</logging>
                                <propertyFileWillOverride>false</propertyFileWillOverride>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>update</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                            <artifactId>liquibase-mssql</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.0</version>
                        </dependency>                           
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                            <artifactId>liquibase-oracle</artifactId>
                            <version>3.1</version>
                        </dependency>                           
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>

            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.xml</include>
                        <include>**/*.csv</include>
                        <include>**/*.sql</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*.csv</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*.sql</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </resource>
            </resources>            
        </build>
```

You can always use the parameterized build with Maven, adding default values as:

```
<properties>   
    <liquibase.clearCheckSums>true</liquibase.clearCheckSums>   
    <database.username>userSchema</database.username>   
    <database.password>myUserPassword</database.password>   
    <database.adminschema.username>adminSchema</database.adminschema.username> 
    <database.adminschema.password>myAdminPassword</database.adminschema.password> 
    <database.liquibasecontext>!IntegrationTesting</database.liquibasecontext> 
</properties>
```

Hope that this may help you.